# nested for loops with changing variables time complexity PT 2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

So my last question, can be found:
[nested for loops with changing variables time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598166/nested-for-loops-with-changing-variables-time-complexity/23598240?noredirect=1#23598240)
and I'm still asking roughly the same question. This time around i'd like to know:
If I was asked this question on an exam, and didn't have access to a computer where I could type up this code to count how many iterations happen per loop. How would I go about deriving (n-2) * (n-1)/2 * n/3 ? the (n-2) part is very clear, the n-1/2 somewhat makes sense, and the n/3, i'm just not sure about.

```
        public static void function2(){
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a value for n: ");
int n = scanner.nextInt();
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= (n-2); i++){
    System.out.println("Entered outer loop");
    for (int j = i+1; j<= (n-1); j++){
        System.out.println("Entered middle loop");
        for (int k = j+1; k<= n; k++){
            System.out.println("Entered inner loop");
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
 System.out.println("Hello world printed: " + counter + " times");
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your answer a little bit to me? I somewhat understand how sigma k=j+1 to n = (n-j) but could use a little bit of an explanation. As well as for all the math past that point. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image: http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn1294.png]

Finish it, correct the mistakes i made (if any), and u get the total number of iterations.